# How to keep bluetooth icon in menu bar even when disconnected in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, and I noticed that the Bluetooth icon only displays at the top of the menu bar when there is an active connection with a Bluetooth device. I would like to keep the icon there even when there is no Bluetooth connection / Bluetooth is off. Is there a way to do this?

I tried installing indicator-bluetooth, but that didn't appear to do anything. I looked in the main Settings app and didn't see a relevant configuration item for this behavior. I also checked GNOME Tweaks, but did not find a relevant configuration item there, either.

In fact, I do see some Bluetooth settings available if I click on the menubar as a whole. But I would prefer to see Bluetooth always up at the top alongside the WiFi, volume, and battery indicators.

Comment: I am also interested in this. It would be nice to have a B icon which is grey when disconnected and white when connected.

Comment: Oh man, every time I need to connect it makes me so sad. I go up to that area of the menu bar and realize I'm not using a mac anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, since you didn't mention already trying it:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

It's the command suggested twice on Ubuntu Forums:

1. [No bluetooth icon on top bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352496/no-bluetooth-icon-on-top-bar)
2. [Bluetooth Icon disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84886/bluetooth-icon-disappeared)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125904)

Comment: @Toto The essential part of the answer is the command i quoted. I don't see a reason to provide more text when the command should do.

Comment: @Toto It's not a link-only answer as you accused it of being.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the complete answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/84886/bluetooth-icon-disappeared :

> I had same issue when I did an update for Ubuntu 11.10. Today I got
> the problem solved.
>
> Just had to install blueman like this:
>
> `sudo apt-get install blueman`
>
> Got it solved, bluetooth icon is now back in the unity top bar.